# EasyPHP - Unexpected end of Apache

Tags: apache, easyphp

I'm trying to start the EasyPHP, but the Apache is show me this error. In the EasyPHP logs the following message appears:

**EasyPHP ServerBase::TimerProc : GetProcessVersion Apache (pid: 11332) error 5**

I checked the processes that were running, but none was on port 80. (And I don't have Skype)

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache config file.Search "Listen" and check if you have added the local ip entry to the config. If Yes then the your local ip may have changed and you have to update the same in the apache config file.